# Proof that a subset closed under group operation of a finite group is a subgroup

Tags: group-theory

I have some idea, lets take any element $a$ from that subgroup and repeatedly apply group operator over it, since group is finite that element $a$ will appear again after some time, $\{a, a^2, a^3,...,a\}.$

Then element previous to 2nd $a$ should be identity element. And prior to it is $a$'s inverse. Hence it has all property of groups. Is this proof correct.

I am not sure about that can 2nd $a$ appear only if we have identity element in it. Please help.

Reference: Fraleigh p.58  Question 5.50 in A First Course in Abstract Algebra

Comment: "since group is finite" - did you want to add finiteness as a condition?

Comment: By group do you mean finite group? And what do you mean by closed subset? Closed under the group multiplication? Or closed under multiplication and inverse? (It makes no difference for finite groups.)

Comment: This works for all groups, not just finite ones, provided that the set is closed under taking products and inverses. And it works also if the subset is closed under taking $ab^{-1}$ for all $a,b$ in the subset (which sometimes makes verifications easier.)

Comment: If you just mean closed under the group multiplication, then closed does not mean subgroup unless the group is finite. Consider for example the non-negative integers as a closed subset of the group of all integers with addition. This is not a subgroup

Answer (score 18):

While you are working in the right direction, it is *a priori* not clear that $a$ itself will repeat. In principle we might have a sequence of powers like $a,a^2,a^3, a^4, a^2, a^3, a^4, a^2, \ldots$.

However, if $G$ is a **group** and $A$ is a **finite nonempty subset** of $G$ that is **closed under multiplication**, then for any $a\in A$ the map $\mathbb N\to G$, $n\mapsto a^n$ is in fact a map $f\colon \mathbb N\to A$ (by induction on $n$) and cannot be injectve because $A$ is finite, so you will have *some* natural numbers $n,m$ with $n<m$ and $a^n=a^m$. Then $m=n+k$ with $k\in \mathbb N$ and we conclude $1=a^{k}\in A$. If $a=1$ then trivially $a^{-1}\in A$ as well. If $a\ne 1$, on the other hand, then clearly $k>1$ and we find $a^{-1}=a^{k-1}\in A$. So we see that $A$ is indeed a subgroup.

Comment: I have just updated question. Sorry for this.

Comment: @VimalRajSharma As you may note from my answer, it is not needed that $G$ is finite, it suffices that $A$ is finite.

Comment: But doesn't closed under group operator thing will make a difference.