# Permutations in $S_{A}$ fixing all the elements in a subset $B\subset A$ form a subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-groups

Let $A$ be a finite set, and $B$ a subset of $A$. Let $G$ be the subset of $S_A$ consisting of all the permutations $f$ of $A$ such that $f(x) = x$ for every $ x \in B$. Prove that $G$ is a subgroup of $S_A$.

I am thinking of starting off by showing that $G$ is closed with respect to the inverse, but I am unsure if this is the correct way to go about it.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Show that $ab\in G$ for all $a,b$ in G. That is enough.

Answer (score 0):

$A$ is finite, so $S_A$ is finite.

In general a subset of a finite group that is closed under multiplication is a subgroup of it.

For a proof of this see [the answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/475975/75923) on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/475966/75923).

So it is enought to prove that $f,g\in G\implies f\circ g\in G$ wich can be classified as trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [subgroup test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup_test).

Clearly $1_{S_A}\in G$, so $G\neq \varnothing$. Let $f,g\in G$ and $x_i\in B$. The set $\{g(x_j)\}_{j=1}^n$ is a collection of $|B|=n$ distinct elements of $B$ since $x_j\neq x_k\implies g(x_j)\neq g(x_k)$ since $g$ is injective. Hence there exists $x_j\in B$ so that $g(x_j) = x_i$. So $g^{-1}(x_i) = x_j\in B$, and hence $f(g^{-1}(x_i))\in B$. So $fg^{-1}\in G$ and therefore by the subgroup test, $G$ is a group.